# Custom express-validator validator doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I have problem in my code, i set validation for check email if already in database, other validation its work but in validation for email not work

this my code in Controller

```
AuthController.register = (req, res) => {

//EMAIL
req.checkBody('email')
.isEmail().withMessage( "must be provided" )
.custom((value, req ) => {
    return AuthController.findUserByEmail(req, value).then(user => {
        if(user == true){
            return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
        }
    });
}).withMessage('E-mail already in use');
}
```

this code not retuning error, can help me for resolve this

Comment: So what happens when you run this code?

Comment: i not get error email already in use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding express-validator, what you are doing wrong is the unwrapping of the 2nd argument to get `req`; [`.custom()` takes a `validator(value, { req, location, path })` function](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#customvalidator).

Just change it like below:

```
// before
// .custom((value, req ) => {
// after
.custom((value, { req }) => {
```

...then, if your `AuthController.findUserByEmail()` logic is correct, it should work as you expected ;)